# MATLAB and Octave on the same system?

Tags: matlab, octave

Should I expect any kind of complications from installing MATLAB on a system which already has Octave installed?

Comment: Please read [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) to help others in the future.

Comment: I do not see how my question does not directly involve tools used primarily for programming. Can you please elaborate?

Comment: On a sidenote: I have to say I really like stackexchange/stackoverflow, but the amount of effort people here put into finding a reason to close every other question with clearly not relevant or totally vague reasons is amusing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No. They are completely different programs and it's no different than you running Minecraft and MATLAB on the same system. They each have their own binaries, configuration files, etc.

Comment: [Minecraft in MATLAB](https://github.com/LeifRoss/MatLab)?